# Failed to Connect to a Windows Service’ Error Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista

Today, when I started my system I got this following error:

> "Failed to Connect to a Windows Service Error"

I have tried to create a new user as administrator, but I was unable to find the cause.

Comment: Have you checked the Event Viewer for errors?

Comment: @Karan When I tried to access Event Viewer, I got this error "Event log service is unavailable."

Comment: In the Windows 7 `services.msc` list there's **Windows Event Collector** which AFAIK is set to Manual by default, and **Windows Event Log**, which is set to Automatic by default. Check these (or whatever's named closest in Vista), start the latter if necessary, reboot and see what gets logged.

Comment: Sounds like that might be the problem. You can access services through the control panel under "Administrative tools" - find the event log service and ensure it is set to "Automatic" startup. That will allow you to see if any other services aren't starting which should be.

Comment: @Karan It has already set to automatic